# Parsing XML String From WebServer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml

Alright, so here's where I'm at with my app.
I've got some code that connects to a remote server and grabs some XML data, and forms it into a string. Here is the code below:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
NSString *accept = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/xml"];
[request addValue:accept forHTTPHeaderField: @"Accept"];
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString* responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",responseString);
```

Which returns

[image]

That's exactly the information I want.  My question is how I can get the double value out of the gold brackets and into my application to use.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried to search for *anything?* It doesn't seem so. Also, this is not related to Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of tutorials of how to use `NSXMLParser`. For example, [ray wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3018) or [here](http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Parsing_XML_data_with_NSXMLParser) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/248883/Objective-C-Fundamentals-NSXMLParser).

Comment: Updated code.  Still having issues. Returns null! http://cl.ly/image/2q2v1j2P0K0k

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few XML parsing options available - ranging from libxml2, to NSXMLParser and a host of open-source projects.

One of my favorite XML parsers is [RaptureXML](https://github.com/ZaBlanc/RaptureXML), which can be installed via [CocoaPods](http://www.cocoapods.org/?q=RaptureXML).

I like to create a category on RXMLElement to parse as follows:

```
- (PFCurrentConditions*)asCurrentCondition
{      

    NSString* summary = [[self child:@"weatherDesc"] text];
    PFTemperature* temp = [PFTemperature temperatureWithFahrenheitString:[[self child:@"temp_F"] text]];
    NSString* humidity = [[self child:@"humidity"] text];
    NSString* wind =
            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wind: %@ km %@", [[self child:@"windspeedKmph"] text], [[self child:@"winddir16Point"] text]];
    NSString* imageUri = [[self child:@"weatherIconUrl"] text];

    return [PFCurrentConditions conditionsWithSummary:summary temperature:temp humidity:humidity wind:wind imageUrl:imageUri];

}
```

**So, you can then use it as follows:**

```
RXMLElement* rootElement = [RXMLElement elementFromXMLData:response.responseData];    
__autoreleasing PFWeatherReport* weatherReport = [rootElement asWeatherReport];
```

Again, this is one of countless options, but my personal favorite.